# packaging heasoft with conda build on macOS Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0

Tags: macos, conda, fits

I need a subset of heasoft libraries for my data reduction pipeline, which I want to release as a `conda` package.
I have recipes which work fine under Linux, but I have problems in OSX when I build the heasoft package.

I do this:

1. download the needed libraries from [the proper source](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/) as a tar file in recipe directory;
2. set `path` keyword in `meta.yaml` with the recipe directory;
3. in `build.sh`, I `cd` into the proper directory, which is `BUILD_DIR` as for any heasoft package.

Now, after exporting all the needed variables (`CC` and others), I do launch `./configure`, and start seeing behaviours I can't deal with.

These are the first lines for the configure:

```
francesco:heasoft-osx(master)*$ conda build .
Attempting to finalize metadata for heasoft
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for heasoft
BUILD START: ['heasoft-6.24-h9b869f0_1.tar.bz2']
Copying /Users/francesco/ascisoft-recipes/heasoft-osx to /Users/francesco/anaconda3/conda-bld/heasoft_1525868116683/work
source tree in: /Users/francesco/anaconda3/conda-bld/heasoft_1525868116683/work
/Users/francesco/anaconda3/conda-bld/heasoft_1525868116683/work/heasoft-6.24/BUILD_DIR
configure: WARNING: /usr/bin/perl and /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin/clang may not work well together!
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
configure: WARNING: no header file found for arc4random
configure: WARNING: Cannot find idn library
configure: WARNING: Compilation of Fortran wrappers and PGSBOX disabled
configure: WARNING: CFITSIO disabled
configure: WARNING: PGPLOT disabled
configure: WARNING: Compilation of WCS utilities disabled
```

If, instead, with the downloaded tar file, I make the usual steps for compiling, I get fair outputs

```
francesco:BUILD_DIR$ ./configure --with-components="heacore heatools"
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Will force readline build on Darwin if available
Found component heacore
Found heacore/BUILD_DIR/hd_config_info
Found component heatools
```

...

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
checking for strip... strip
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... make
checking whether make is GNU make... yes
```

and so on.

I would stop here, but the building process goes on and I have even more annoying behaviour, such as

```
ignoring file /[...]/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/lib/libape_2.9.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

Is it something related to my system settings coupling with `conda-build`?

If needed, I can provide my recipe of course.